# Jquery Display round tag image under image issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add round tag Images(25*25 pixel) on all Image tags in the html Dom.
It works but with my code the position sometimes changes and it often displayed under the Image.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery("img").each(function() {
    var image = jQuery(this);
    if ((image.width() >= 512) && (image.width() <= 2048)){
        image.parent().css('display', 'inline-block');
        var top_pos = image.offset().top+200, left_pos = image.offset().left+150;                       
        image.parent().append('<div class="tag_image first_tag_image1" id="first_draggable1" style="position:absolute;'+'top:'+top_pos+'px;'+'left:'+left_pos+'px;">');
        //do something
    }
});
```

Anybody who knows what to do?
If any question please add a comment.

Comment: Give us https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You could achive this just with css. Add a `:before` or `:after` element to your images with the style you want for example.

Comment: @Gonzalo Thank you very much. I've solved problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use :before.
For example image.before('//some code')